# Confused on how to implement Javascript audio to a snake game?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a snake game that I'm making through Javascript but I'm a little bit uncertain as to how to add audio. I have Sam's Teach Yourself Javascript in 24 Hours, looked through stackoverflow questions and youtube tutorials but my confusion stems from the fact that I don't have an audio tag in my index.html. In fact, I'm unsure as to whether I would need one or not. Here is the content of my single index.html file:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width='450' height='450'></canvas>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/snake.js"></script>
```

All I have is a single javascript file and a canvas. Below is a snippet of my .js file with the snake functionality. I'm only including the audio portion that I'm struggling on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = $('#canvas').width();
    var h = $('#canvas').height();

    var cw = 10;
    var d;
    var food;
    var score;
    var eating_sound = "Eating-SoundBible.com-1470347575.mp3";

    var snake_array;

    function init() {
        d = "right";
        create_snake();
        create_food();
        score = 0;
        if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") 
            clearInterval(game_loop);
        game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);
    }

    init();
```

Here is where I'm trying to call the mp3 file. When the snake eats a block:

```
 if(nx == food.x && ny == food.y)
  {
    var tail = {x: nx, y: ny};
    create_food();
    score++;
    eating_sound.play();
  }
```

This doesn't feel right to me and it obviously isn't because it doesn't work. But do I need to create  tags in my .html with autoplay? Is this the correct way to do this? I would think that I wouldn't need to create audio tags because I don't have any html elements in my index.html. In my mind it should load with the Javascript file. Right?

Revision------------

Thanks for the answers and comments below, but I'm still a little bit confused as to how this works for the audio. This is taken from the Mozilla Developer Network Docs, provided by Derek below.

```
mySound = new Audio([URLString]);
```

The audio file I downloaded isn't a URL string. Do I need to host it somewhere, much like how you would host a picture on tinypic.com and then link to it?

I revised my code to have my eating sound set to a variable as so:

```
var eating_sound = new Audio(["Eating-SoundBible.com-1470347575.mp3"]);
```

Just like the doc says except of course that its not a URL. Afterwards I try to call it like so:

```
if(nx == food.x && ny == food.y)
{
  var tail = {x: nx, y: ny};
  create_food();
  score++;
  new Audio(eating_sound).play();
}
```

Now is this supposed to create an audio tag in my html? I thought about it some more and it seems that the UrlString looks like its a method, also shown in the docs. I tried UrlString(Eating-SoundBible.com....etc.) but that didn't work either. Am I getting closer? My big question now is, do I need to have something in my index.html file or is the Audio constructor doing it for me? I just want this to work.

Comment: `new Audio(eating_sound).play()`

Comment: Why are you calling `.play` on a String...

Comment: Thanks for your reply megawac, but no dice. It still doesn't work. Is there some place I can refer to where you got the new Audio syntax? Also, would you agree that I don't need an audio tag in my index.html or would I need something like that?

Comment: If I take out the quotations it will break because of the integers in within the .mp3

Answer (score 1):

`eating_sound` is a String. In JavaScript you cannot have a variable referring directly to a file. To play a sound you *have* to use an `<audio>` tag in order to play an `mp3` file.

A fast way to create an `<audio>` node (technical name: `HTMLAudioElement`) is to use [the `Audio` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement):

```
new Audio(eating_sound).play();
```

By the way, your statement "In my mind it should load with the Javascript file" is incorrect. Every file has to be load into DOM in order to be manipulated. For example, if you need to load and manipulate an image in JavaScript, you have to load it by creating an `<img>` tag through `Image` constructor. There is no other way of doing it.)

Comment: Awesome I'll take a look at this. Thanks for the link Derek.